# Cant boot windows from usb because of grub error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, usb

So here i am, with that grub error, which happens after you delete linux partitions but your grub is still here. And I need to remove it and get on my windows. Which i cant, because no matter what i do, type commands in grub,or try to boot linux or windows from usb - they don't boot. I set usb as number 1 in bios and it still doesn't boot, all i get is grub error.

Comment: Which software did you use to write windows to your usb?

Comment: Rufus, i tried to write linux and it didn't boot, tried windows xp - didn't boot.

Comment: Presumably your Windows XP USB drive is not bootable (tradidtionally Windows <10 did not support booting from USB but there are guides to overcome this).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you broke your grub, grub rescue in which you are right now wont work as it wont recognize most commands you put in. If you want get back windows bootloader you need a windows disk and then you will have to boot from it. Select repair your computer instead of install now and follow wizard. Either open startup repair to do autmoated repair or open a command prompt for manual. Now fix your mbr and bootsector,

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
```

That would be enough. Reboot and you will have your windoze bootloader back, if not you will have to get back to command prompt and type in

```
bootsect /nt60 all
```

Reboot afterwards. goodluck.

Comment: But what if my windows xp (i downloaded them because they took less space and i was in hurry) doesn't boot? It is bootable, i tested on other computer

Comment: @hira Hi, Best would be to boot from a cd/dvd, set priority of your dvd writer at first to make computer boot from cd. If you want to make a pendrive bootable you could do so using command `dd if=/path/to/isofile.iso of=/path/to/device`. Also do you want to repair windows 7 bootloader or xp? I have posted solution for win 7.

Comment: For windows 7, just somewhere on internet i saw that for fixing any windows cd works. Should propably go and buy cd now and try to write windows 7 to it.

Comment: Windows xp uses different type of bootloader, same goes for windows 8, however both will be able to detect windows 7. Best would be for you to use windows 7 dvd for restoring windows 7 bootloader.

Comment: @Hira also check your your boot order in bios. It decides which device gets booted first. It should have your cd/dvd writer at top if you want to boot from dvd.